# Javascript to check for empty form elements, deny submit if empty, send alert message

Tags: javascript, forms, alert

So I've been looking around at code and seeing what is possible through javascript. I have a code that currently checks if a form has empty elements and denies it to be submitted if any are empty. The thing is I tried to add an alert if the elements were empty and an alert if the elements were not empty but it did not work. I don't seem to know enough about java script to go about editing it.

Here is the form. Ignore the weird class and div names, they are set that way because the form submits to a google doc spreadsheet.

```
<form class="quickemailform" action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dGp3YUxCTGtWd251ZXVfOEtwc1hhWVE6MQ&amp;ifq" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;" id="ss-form" name="frm1" onsubmit="InputChecker()">
        <br>
        <div class="errorbox-good">
            <div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                <div class="ss-form-entry">
                    <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0">
                    <font class="formtitles">FULL NAME:</font>
                    </br>
                    <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_0"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_0" size="42">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="errorbox-good">
            <div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                <div class="ss-form-entry">
                    <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_1">
                        <font class="formtitles" id="compnam">COMPANY NAME:</font>
                        </br>
                    <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_1"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="entry.1.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1" size="42">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="errorbox-good">
            <div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                <div class="ss-form-entry">
                    <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_2">
                        <font class="formtitles"  id="emailadd">EMAIL ADDRESS:</font>
                        <br>
                    <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_2"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="entry.2.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_2" size="42">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="errorbox-good">
            <div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-paragraph-text">
                <div class="ss-form-entry">
                    <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_3">
                        <font class="formtitles"  id="request">Your Request:</font>
                        <font class="fineprint">( SUMMARIZE IMPORTANT DETAILS )</font>
                        <br>
                    </label>
                    <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_3"></label>
                    <textarea name="entry.3.single" cols="32" rows="10" class="ss-q-long" id="entry_3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="backupCache" value="">

        <div class="ss-item ss-navigate"><div class="ss-form-entry">
                <input class="submitbuttons" type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;" src="" border="0" onclick="myFunction()"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the javascript that denies the form to be submitted if any fields are empty. I got this code online, I did not write it myself. It is tested and works but I want it to do more than just deny submission.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

              (function() {
        var divs = document.getElementById('ss-form').
        getElementsByTagName('div');
        var numDivs = divs.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < numDivs; j++) {
        if (divs[j].className == 'errorbox-bad') {
        divs[j].lastChild.firstChild.lastChild.focus();
        return;
        }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        if (div.className == 'ss-form-entry' &&
        div.firstChild &&
        div.firstChild.className == 'ss-q-title') {
        div.lastChild.focus();
        return;
        }
        }
        })();
    </script>
```

If possible I want to know how I can add an alert for when the form is denied or accepted. Also if the form is denied I would like to have it so that I have something like

```
<font class="asterick" div="your_name_ast">*</font>   or   <font class="asterick" div="company_name_ast">*</font>
```

and have the asterick show up next to each empty element if the form is denied not submitted. Such as having the form check each element to be empty or not. If the script finds the element to be empty an alert would pop up saying "Form is not filled. Please look over all elements with a *." and then it would have the asterisk appear.

Thanks to anyone that has read this far.

EDIT: Doing some looking around more and it seems that alerts are considered bad practice. Is this true? Is there some other way I might go about letting users know if the elements are empty?

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and/or similar? Unsure what you mean by "alert when denied", but the idea is that the user is "guided" through the form entries until such time the user has provided enough (validated) info to proceed.

Comment: Denied as in the javascript keeps the form from being submitted if any form elements are empty.

Comment: When using html5, you can add required into the input and then, the browser will check on submit, if the input is not empty or invalid, like on input field with type email and no email address typed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery Validate (or similar) like EdSF mention or you could just change the submit button into a regular button that when click it calls a function to validate your fields and if non are empty submit the form. I haven't tested the following code, but you get the idea.

```
function validateForm(){
  var isValid = true;

  var elements = document.getElementById('ss-form').getElementsByTagName('input');

  for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].value.length < 1){
      isValid = false;
    }
  }

  if(isValid){
    document.getElementById('ss-form').submit();
  }
  else {
    alert('Please fill all required fields');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could accomplish everything you want to do. jQuery is very easy to learn. Here is a sample of your code using jQuery:

This is a very minimal example of what you can do.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#entry_0').blur(function()
{
var Fullname = $(this).val();
$('#nameresult').css("display","none");
if(Fullname.length>0)
    {
    $('#nameresult').css("display","inline-block");
    $('#nameresult').css("color","#00BB00");
    $('#nameresult').html("Valid")
    return true;
    }
    $('#nameresult').css("display","inline-block");
    $('#nameresult').css("color","#ff0000");
    $('#nameresult').html("Input Needed")
    $(this).focus();
    return;    
    });


$('#entry_1').blur(function()
{
var Companyname = $(this).val();
$('#companyresult').css("display","none");
if(Companyname.length>0)
    {
    $('#companyresult').css("display","inline-block");
    $('#companyresult').css("color","#00BB00");
    $('#companyresult').html("Valid")
    return true;
    }
    $('#companyresult').css("display","inline-block");
    $('#companyresult').css("color","#ff0000");
    $('#companyresult').html("Input Needed")
    $(this).focus();
    return;    
    });

  });

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form >
FULL NAME:<input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_0" size="42">
<div id="nameresult" style="display: none;"></div>
<br>

COMPANY NAME:<input type="text" name="entry.1.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1" size="42">
<div id="companyresult" style="display:none;"></div>
<br>

EMAIL ADDRESS:<input type="text" name="entry.2.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_2" size="42"><br>

Your Request:<textarea name="entry.3.single" cols="32" rows="10" class="ss-q-long" id="entry_3"></textarea><br><br>

<input class="submitbuttons" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" src="" border="0" />

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please forgive the code formatting, I typed it up very quickly.

Here is a link to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working model that I've used on an email encrypting site:
http://jsfiddle.net/2b6d5/46/

Feel free to add to it, change it... post any forks/updates here.
:)

```
/*
 * validate an e-mail address by leveraging the HTML5
 * input element with type "email"
 */

function validate() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type='email';
  input.value=document.getElementById('valid').value;

  if (input.checkValidity()) {
    document.getElementById('address').style.background = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('address').style.background = 'red';
  }

  return false;
}

function val2(){
      var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type='email';
  input.value=document.getElementById('valid').value;
    if (input.checkValidity()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");  
    return false;
}
}
```